# Javascript: Access public variable from private function

Tags: javascript, oop

I am learning javascript and was trying out some code below. I am calling the below javascript object as

```
var client=new atrmsClient('6247543');

var val=client.getRosterData();
```

I get an error on this line:

```
var postData= {"cmdShow": "Show", "txtEmpId" : EmpId, "txtPeopleSoft_Id": EmpId, "__VIEWSTATE":  viewState   }
```

EmpId is undefined. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
"use strict";

function atrmsClient(EmployeeId)
{
    this.EmpId=EmployeeId;

    var siteUrl="http://wncrpma011.japa.ad.aexp.com/TransportRoster/EmployeeReport.aspx";


    var getViewState=function()
    {

            $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: siteUrl,
            dataType: 'html',           
            processData: false,
                xhrFields: 
                {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
        })
        .done(ExtractViewState).fail(errorFunc).always(alwaysFunc);

        return "";

    };

    var SendPostRequest=function(viewState)
    {
        var postData= {"cmdShow": "Show", "txtEmpId" : EmpId, "txtPeopleSoft_Id": EmpId, "__VIEWSTATE":  viewState   }

            $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: siteUrl,
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'html',           
            processData: false,
                xhrFields: 
                {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
        })
        .done(parseRosterData).fail(errorFunc).always(alwaysFunc);


    };


    var parseRosterData=function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);



    };

    var ExtractViewState=function(data)
    {

        var rawResponse=data;
        var viewState=$(rawResponse).find('input[name=__VIEWSTATE]')[0].value;
        console.log(viewState);

        SendPostRequest(viewState);

    };

    var errorFunc=function()
    {


    };


    var alwaysFunc=function()
    {


    };

    this.getRosterData=function()
    {
        var viewStateVal=getViewState();
        console.log("calling");
        return "";
    };



}
```

Comment: You have to access it with `this.EmpId`

Comment: @thefourtheye — Different function. Different value of `this`.

Comment: this.EmpId is not working

Comment: @Quentin Oh yeah, its called from a callback. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never declare a variable called `EmpId`.

The only `EmpId` you have is a *property* of the `atrmsClient` instance.

Add

```
var EmpId = EmployeeId;
```

… or just use `EmployeeId` as that is still in scope.

Comment: I am confused. Can I not directly access the property of atrmsClient inside that function ?

Comment: @MadhurAhuja — You can never access a property of an object (other than the default object (`window` in a browser), and then only if you aren't using strict mode) *directly*. If you had a reference to the object in a variable (which, inside that function, you currently don't) then you could access the property through that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be:

```
function atrmsClient(EmployeeId) {

    var that = this;
    this.EmpId=EmployeeId;

    var SendPostRequest=function(viewState) {
        var postData= {"cmdShow": "Show", "txtEmpId" : that.EmpId, "txtPeopleSoft_Id": that.EmpId, "__VIEWSTATE":  viewState   }
        // ...
    };

}
```

It depends if you need `EmpId` to be available from outside, i.e. using `client.EmpId`. If yes, then this solution should suit your needs. Otherwise, use @Quentin's.